# Cannot select gnome shell when logging in anymore 12.04

Tags: gnome, login, login-screen

suddenly the "GNOME" option when logging in to ubuntu disappeared.
I have absolutely no idea why. `apt-get remove gnome-shell && apt-get install gnome-shell` didn't have any effect.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Still don't really know what the problem was, but

```
apt-get remove gnome && apt-get install gnome
```

solved it...